# bash: iterate over list of floating numbers

Tags: bash, for-loop, floating-point

In bash script, I want to iterate over a list of values that I want to pass as parameters to a script in python. It turns out that `$d` and `$minFreq` aren't floats when passed to the python script. Why does this happen?

```
for d in {0.01, 0.05, 0.1}
do
    for i in {1..3}
    do
        someString=`python scrpt1.py -f myfile --delta $d --counter $i| tail -1`
        for minFreq in {0.01, 0.02}
        do
            for bValue in {10..12}
            do
                python testNEW.py $someString -d $bValue $minFreq
            done
        done
    done
done
```

Comment: Lose the spaces around the equals sign in the `someString = $(python ...)` line (with back-ticks replaced by `$(...)` because getting back-ticks into a comment as back-ticks is tricky, at best.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Either remove the spaces

```
for d in {0.01,0.05,0.1}
```

or don't use the {} expansion (it's not necessary here):

```
for d in 0.01 0.05 0.1
```

The same applies to the `minFreq` loop.

---

As written,

```
for d in {0.01, 0.05, 0.1}
```

the variable `d` is assigned the literal string values `{0.01,`, `0.05,`, and `0.1}`.

Comment: While the spaces in the expansion are unnecessary, the Python process should not see them at all, I think.  I'd expect the shell to remove the spaces when constructing the argument list since the shell variables are not quoted.

Comment: The spaces prevent brace expansion from taking place, so the braces and commas are not syntax, but included in the strings passed to python.